# SQL Table design for a dynamic scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a ticket details table with n number of columns.Each project has a specific configuration to select a specific number of columns to find the repeat count of same value ticket.Currently,i have a table with fixed column names with the values saved and frequency maintained for all projects.

Table 1:Ticket Details

```
TicketID | Column1  | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |ProjectN    
T1       | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |XYZ
T2       | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |XYZ
T3       | Priority1| High    | M1      | S1      |XYZ
T4       | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |ABC
T5       | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |ABC
```

Table 2 with Fixed Columns:

```
ID | Column1  | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |ProjectN | Frequency
1  | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |XYZ       |2
2  | Priority1| High    | M1      | S1      |XYZ       |1
3  | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1      |ABC       |2
```

Now,i need to achieve the same value storage logic with count with varied columns for each project 
For eg:If project 1 chooses column1, column2, column3 then resultant table should have these 3 column values and count of tickets

Similarly the next project can choose column1,column3 and if so then for this project values should be tracked for these 2 and count. 
Need to achieve this logic in a single sql server table dynamically that contains the values of chosen columns and the repetitive count from the ticket details table.
Kindly help with how to build the logic with sql table.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Have you tried dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

Change your structures to be

Table 1: TicketTypes

```
TicketTypeID | Column1  | Column2 | Column3 | Column4  
1            | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1  
2            | Priority1| High    | M1      | S1
```

Table 2: Tickets

```
TicketID | TicketTypeID |ProjectN    
T1       | 1            |XYZ
T2       | 1            |XYZ
T3       | 2            |XYZ
T4       | 1            |ABC
T5       | 1            |ABC
```

Then you would fill TicketTypes with the unique combination of columns that are used by projects (do a check before you try to insert into the tickets table).  You will also need to decide on either a value that means that column is not applicable or set it to NULL.

Then join on this ticket type table with your ticket details to identify which type it belongs. (If you set your columns as nullable, then you will need to do an ISNULL() in your join to join on these values as well).

Then for example you can have this in your ticket types table:

```
TicketTypeID | Column1  | Column2 | Column3 | Column4  
1            | Priority1| Low     | M1      | S1  
2            | Priority1| High    | M1      | S1  
3            | Priority1| NULL    | M1      | NULL
4            | NULL     | High    | NULL    | S1  
5            | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
```

Now do you need the table to actually exist for you to see the frequency? Or is this just for reporting purposes?  Otherwise, how often do you update the table?  You may be better with a view or stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT
    tType.Column1
    , tType.Column2
    , tType.Column3
    , tType.Column4
    , tickets.ProjectN
    , COUNT(1) AS Frequency
FROM TicketTypes AS tTypes
JOIN Tickets 
    ON tickets.TicketTypeID = tTypes.TicketTypeID
GROUP BY tType.Column1, tType.Column2, tType.Column3, tType.Column4, tickets.ProjectN
```

Comment: Yes the table should have frequency column to know the count of repetitive tickets.

Comment: Yeah the issue with that is the number of repetitive tickets will change so you will need to keep updating the table to reflect this.  You may be better making a view or stored procedure to produce your final table that way it will always deliver up-to-date information when you query it

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic SQL way is this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select '+ @columns + N', ProjectN, count(*) Frequency from [Table 1] group by '+ @columns + N', ProjectN';
exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
```

That `@columns` is an input string like `N'column1, column2, column3'`, You can use this in a stored procedure.